# Monitor performance of a task in multiple processes

Tags: prometheus, grafana, monitoring, statsd

I have a task that starts in one process and ends in another. I like to monitor performance of the task from start to end.

> As the processes are running in different machines, I cannot trust their time.

I am using StatsD for monitoring and statistics. Is there a way that I can achieve this?

---

I think (based on the search and suggestions in other questions) I should have something like:

```js
// In the process where the task starts
var StatsD = require('node-statsd'),
    client = new StatsD();

// Sends a signal that shows task is started
client.A_METRIC_OR_SOMETHING('task.start.' + taskId, 1); // Or client.A_METRIC_OR_SOMETHING(['task.start.', taskId], 1);

// In the process where the task ends
var StatsD = require('node-statsd'),
    client = new StatsD();

// Same thing for the end.
client.A_METRIC_OR_SOMETHING('task.end.' + taskId, 1);
```

Now, what I need is a way to create a graph or dataset out of these logs.

Comment: What you want is a trace. You can instrument your code to export traces using any instrumentation library and export the metrics to any datasource that supports traces, e.g: opentelemetry, jaeger, etc.
check https://opentelemetry.io/